# How to ignore '\n' while comparing two lists

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have two lists. I want to check if one list is a subset of other list or not.

```
list1 = ['12345678\n', '87654321']
list2 = ['01234567','12345678', '87654321', '23456789']
```

The problem is my first list i.e. **list1** will always contain **\n** since I'm reading it from a file which has item(s) in separate lines.But I want to ignore this **\n** and continue comparing.The below code of mine is always going into **else** part. Is there any way to acheive the **True** scenario without modifying both the lists ?
**My code below:**

```
flag = True                 # Initialized value of flag to default 'True' at beginning

for val in list1:
  if val not in list2:
     flag = False

if flag == True
  ....                          # Do some operation if flag is 'True'
  ....
else
  print 'list1 is not a subset of list2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strip` to strip away all whitespace-characters and then compare that to the items in the second list. Also, you can replace your for loop with `all`:

```
>>> all(e.strip() in list2 for e in list1)
True
```

Further, you might think about stripping the newline character when you create `list1`, and to use `set` instead of `list` to speed up lookup.

```
>>> set(map(str.strip, list1)).issubset(list2)
True
```